# I have this csvReader java code and it is returning only the second line after the header over and over again till the last line index

Tags: java

I have this code:

```html
public class ReadCSVFile {

    public ArrayList<Efo> readFile(File file, Efo efo) {

        ArrayList<Efo> efoList = new ArrayList<Efo>();
        Logger log;
        BufferedReader br = null;


        try {

            FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);
            br = new BufferedReader(fr);
            br.readLine();
            String line=null;
          while((line=br.readLine())!=null){

                String[] csvEfo = line.split("\\|");

                String midID = csvEfo[1];
                String memID = csvEfo[2];

                efo.setMidAppID(midID);
                efo.setMidMemberID(memID);

                efo = new Efo();    
                efoList.add(efo);

                line = br.readLine();

            }



        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());

        } 
        finally {
              try {
                if (br!= null) {
                  //flush and close both "input" and its underlying FileReader
                  br.close();
                }
              }
              catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
              }
            }

        return efoList;
    }

}
```

and I'm calling this arraylist here:

```
public class BEQ_Launcher extends CMSProcessBaseImpl{

    BEQ_Launcher() {}

public void launchData(String appNode, boolean isOverride, boolean isCreateWI) {

        try {

                    efo = new Efo();
            csvInputFile = new ReadCSVFile();
            csvContents = new ArrayList();

      csvContents = csvInputFile.readFile(testFile, efo);
      if(csvContents.size() > 0){
        for (int i=0; i < csvContents.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(efo.getMidMemberID()","efo.getMidAppID());
        }
       }

       other codes...
```

It is only outputting the line after the header over and over again..

What should i do?

When i remove the parameters in readFile and just declare Efo efo = new Efo inside the readFile.. getters are returning null when called..

Efo() class only have all the variable declarations and the getters and setters..

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: Because you should create new Efo instance before calling it's setters. So remove efo parameter in readFile function. Create new efo, call setters, add to the list in your while loop. Then  `System.out.println(csvContents.get(i).getMidMemberID()");` should work.

Answer (score 1):

```
 line = br.readLine();
```

You need to remove the final `readLine()` from this loop. Otherwise you will throw away every even-numbered line. `while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)` does all the line reading you need.

Comment: @AlexanderHeim I am wondering what exactly you think your comment contributes to this answer. It doesn't.